# How do I update Google worksheet with data from separate worksheet based on dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-dates

I have a worksheet of `"Loads"` that contains a growing list of loads done by drivers. This worksheet grows with new rows daily. I am wanting to have a seperate worksheet called `"New Loads"` in the same workbook that only contains the rows from  `"Loads"` that falls withing a date range.

For example, I want to pull all the rows from worksheet `"Loads"` into worksheet `"New Loads"` when the worksheet `"Loads"` cell `A1` `"Delivery date"` falls between worksheet `"New Loads"` cell `A1` `"start date"` and `A2` `"end date"`.

I also am wanting any data pulled into the `"New Loads"` worksheet to overwrite all old date that was previously pulled. So that way the only data in `"New Loads"` is data that matches the date range.

Comment: You can try some mix of `=query + today` functions. Can you share some sample data ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract a report from "Loads" based records that fall between a given "start date" and "end date".

There might be several ways to do this. This answer uses the `QUERY` function to display the record details.

Use this formula:

`=query(Loads!A2:C,"select A, B, C where A>=date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'  and  A<=date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")`

- The "where" clause tests for a delivery date greater than or equal to the "start date" AND a delivery date that is less than or equal to the "end date".

When dates are used as criteria in a query, there are two issues to consider:

- the function expects the dates to be strings. So in this answer, the "start date" and "end date" are converted using `TEXT()`
- the format of the date string must be "yyyy-mm-dd". This has nothing to do with how the date record is formatted; it's just an issue for the query.

---

New Loads

[image: newloads]

---

**Loads**

[image: Loads]